# Apply different HTML5 formatting to the values of keys within hashes that are nested in an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html, loops, hash

I am trying to generate random quotes on each new page in my app.  Each random_quote is a hash with :title, :quote, and :author key/value pairs.  These hashes are nested in an array and I am using the array#sample method to randomly pick one and render on the page.  This is the code I currently have that is working:

```
#module ApplicationHelper
def random_quote
  a = { :title  => "Ebola",
        :quote  => "Foobar",
        :author => "Bill O'Reily"}
  b = { :title  => "ISIS",
        :quote  => "Here I come to save the day!",
        :author => "Mighty Mouse"}

  random_quote_hash = [ a,b ].sample
end

#application view...
<% random_quote.each do |key, value| %>
  <h3><%= random_quote[key] = value %></h3>
<% end %>
```

This code simply renders :title, :quote and :author as HTML elements all with the same formatting.
However, I would like to apply different HTML formatting to the value of each key...

```
eg :title = <h1 class="title">
   :quote = <h3 class="quote">
   :author = <h3 class="author">
```

Seems like this should be super-easy...
If I run the code below, the HTML formatting works for each key value...

```
<% random_quote.each do |key, value| %>
  <h1 class="title"><%= random_quote[:title].upcase %></h1>
  <h3 class="quote">"<%= random_quote[:quote] %>"</h3>
  <h3 class="author"><%= random_quote[:author] %></h3>
<% end >
```

However, each key referenced in the line is randomly sampled via the random_quote method and therefore don't match, i.e. the title won't match the quote and neither will match the author as all will be from different hashes.

Please help a noobie out?  Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

So it appears I was making it too difficult...
After playing around here: http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/92897/7
I came up with:

```
#module ApplicationHelper
 def random_quote
   a = { :title  => "Ebola",
         :quote  => "Foobar",
         :author => "Bill O'Reily"}
   b = { :title  => "ISIS",
         :quote  => "Here I come to save the day!",
         :author => "Mighty Mouse"}

   quotes_array = [ a,b ]

   @random_quote_hash = quotes_array.sample
 end

#Application View
<% random_quote %>
<h3><%= @random_quote_hash[:title] %></h3>
<h1><%= @random_quote_hash[:quote] %></h1>
<p><%= @random_quote_hash[:author] %></p>
```

Would love to see a refactor or slicker way to do this though.  Thanks!!

Comment: Yep this is a good implementation.  You may want to consider using 'content_tag' to generate this whole block for you so that all you would have to call is random_quote.  Ill throw up an example of this in my earlier answer.

Answer (score 2):

Array#sample returns a single random object from an array. http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Array.html#method-i-sample

So i think you just want something like

`<% quote = random_quote %>
  <h1 class="title"><%= quote[:title].upcase %></h1>
  <h3 class="quote">"<%= quote[:quote] %>"</h3>
  <h3 class="author"><%= quote[:author] %></h3>`

Answer (score 1):

As random_quote returns a whole hash I would be assigning and using this object explicitly, there is no need to iterate anything.

```
#module ApplicationHelper
 def random_quote
   a = { :title  => "Ebola",
         :quote  => "Foobar",
         :author => "Bill O'Reily"}
   b = { :title  => "ISIS",
         :quote  => "Here I come to save the day!",
         :author => "Mighty Mouse"}

   quotes_array = [ a,b ]

   random_quote_hash = quotes_array.sample

     content_tag(:h3, random_quote_hash[:title]) + 
        content_tag(:h1, random_quote_hash[:quote]) +
            content_tag(:p, random_quote_hash[:author])
 end

#Application View
<% random_quote %>
```

This should give your desired result and keep your code nice and dry.

More on content tag here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper/content_tag

Comment: Thanks Allan! However, with that I get an error: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer...